# zend webservice

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-soap

im nob in zend, I have create this webservice and i want to call this function in my zend project using the zend soap.

```
function insertion($id,$prenom,$nom,$nele,$ville) 
  { 
     $user = new USER($id,$prenom,$nom,$nele,$ville);
     $user->SaveClient();
     $return="okkkkkkkkkkk";
     return $return;  
  }


 $server->register('insertion',array('id'=>'xsd:string','prenom'=>'xsd:string', 'nom'=>'xsd:string','ne_le'=>'xsd:string','ville'=>'xsd:string'),array('return'=>'xsd:string'),'Namespace');
```

My problem is how can i access to my data base using an extern webservicew not the class Zend_Db_Table_Abstract

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful http://plutov.by/post/web_service_soap

Answer (score 0):

Use Zend_Soap_Client normally

```
$client = new Zend_Soap_Client("http://your.webservice.wsdl");
$client->insertion($p1, $p2, $p3, $p4, $p5)
```

I dont know if you're using Zend_Soap_Server to create the webservice, but Zend_Soap_Cliet can connect to any Webservice using SOAP protocol.